# css 命名の質問

Tags: css

小規模なサイトなのですが、ページが複数ありそのそれぞれでセクションのマージンの取り方が違う場合。
クラス名などはどうしていますか？

```
<section class="section01"></section>
<section class="section01"></section>
<section class="section01"></section>  ←これだけマージンが上下他と違う
<section class="section01"></section>
```

また、そのページ内で一つのブロックのみがマージンの取り方が違う場合はどうしますか？

```
.mb10 {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important
}
```

を許可しますか？

また、見出しなどで、アンダーラインあるなしや、ボールドか、ボールドでないかなど、
同じ文章構造でもページによって若干スタイルが異なる場合の命名を教えて欲しいです。

例えば、文字のボールドあるなしだと

```
.txt_b ←ボールド
.txt　←なし
```

等です。
この微妙なスタイルの違いにいつも命名を悩ませています。

Answer (score 3):

セクションのうち特定のもののみマージンが異なる場合、その意味・理由にも依ると思います。 `mb10`という例から察するにセクションの内容に依存せず特定の位置のマージンを広くする必要があるなら、当該セクションには手を加えるようなことはせず、`<hr/>`タグを挟み、そちらでスタイルを指定する方法もあるかと。

---

ボールドについては`.txt_b`とせずHTML上で`<strong>`タグを使用してスタイル定義も

```
.txt strong { font-weight: bold; }
```

とするのが筋ではないでしょうか？

---

CSSクラス名に困る時点で、適切なスタイル・文書構造でない可能性があります。

Answer (score 0):

特定のsectionだけマージンを変えたいということはそのsectionは他とは異なる意味を持つsectionということだと思います。
それであれば同じクラス名を変えるかクラスを足してスタイルを変えればよいかと思います。

html

```
<section class="section01 hoge"></section>
```

css

```
.section01.hoge {
  /* 他のsectionとは違うスタイルを設定 */
}
```

ページやコンポーネントによって微妙にスタイルが違う場合は上位のクラスを指定したセレクタで解決できないでしょうか。

```
.txt {
  /* 共通のスタイル */
}
.page1 .txt {
  /* ページ1におけるスタイル */
}
.page2 .txt {
  /* ページ2におけるスタイル */
}
```